# I can't make my while loop stop when I want

Tags: c++, loops

Write a while loop that prints `userNum` divided by 2 (integer division) until reaching 1. Follow each number by a space. Example output for `userNum` = 20: `20 10 5 2 1`

```cpp
    #include <iostream> 
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() 
    {    
       int userNum = 0;
    
       userNum = 20;    
       cout << userNum << " ";
       while (userNum > 1)    
       {
          userNum = userNum/2;
          cout << userNum << " ";    
       }    
       cout << endl;
    
       return 0; 
    }
```

It divides properly until I get to 0, where it gives me 0 instead of terminating. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it just keep giving you 0? or does it give you zero 1 time and then terminate?

Comment: The code you've posted behaves exactly like you describe it should, I'm not seeing any 0's as output

Comment: "It divides properly until I get to 0, where it gives me 0 instead of terminating" Do you mean that the program doesn't work if you set `userNum = 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code behaves just like you expect it to.

I am going to suggest changing code a little bit as a matter of good practice.

Instead of:

```
cout << userNum << " ";
while (userNum > 0)    
{
   userNum = userNum/2;
   cout << userNum << " ";    
}
```

Use:

```
while (userNum > 1)    
{
   cout << userNum << " ";    
   userNum = userNum/2;
}
```

The general principle is:

```
while ( <conditional> )
{
   // Use the data

   // Change the data as the last operation in the loop.
}
```

A `for` loop provides natural placeholders for these.

```
for ( <initialize data>; <conditional>; <update data for next iteration> )
{
   // Use the data
}
```

If you were to switch to using a `for` loop, which I recommend, your code would be:

```
for ( userNum = 20; userNum > 0; userNum /= 2 )
{
   cout << userNum << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of these options but none of them worked with the other tests therefore I made some modifications. This works perfect for zybooks.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main() {
    int userNum = 0;
    
    userNum = 40;
    
    cin>>userNum;
    while(userNum>1)
    {
       userNum=userNum/2;
       cout<<userNum<<" ";   
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/SvU8z3

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() 
{    
   int userNum = 20;

   while (userNum > 0)    
   {
      cout << userNum << " ";    
      userNum = userNum/2;
   }    
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers (even if working) aren't really appreciated here. Add some explanations please.

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main() {       
    int userNum;
    cin >> userNum;
    
    while (userNum >= 4) {   
        userNum /= 4;   
        cout<<userNum<<" ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
   return 0;
}
```